# Problem with ar_pose, error: Rectified topic '/camera/image_rect' requested but camera publishing '/camera/camera_info' is uncalibrated**

Tags: ros, ar-pose, uvc-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I successfully calibrated my camera (rosrun uvc_cam_node works well) but when I launch ar_pose I get error that my camera isn't calibrated:

**[ERROR] [1416872150.188997696]: Rectified topic '/camera/image_rect' requested but camera publishing '/camera/camera_info' is uncalibrated**

Please help me and dispel my doubts:

1. Compare two rosnode lists:
   Are they the same? /uvc_camera node =     /camera/uvc_camera_node
2. uvc_camera_node is a node which transmit video from camera to ROS
   and   /camera/uvc_camera_node  is a node which ar_pose use to get video to recognize maker/tag?
3. Compare topic lists:
   /camera_info, /image_raw and /camera/camera_info, /camera/image_raw
   should I remap something in [launch](http://pastebin.com/Q6LTpzRg)?
4. Why in [launch](http://pastebin.com/Q6LTpzRg) we set parameters and after It there is command 'find' which load parameters from file? is there any sense?

DETAILS:
when I ran:
uvc_camera I get:

```
przemek@przem:~/tum_simulator_ws/src/ar_tools/ar_pose/launch$ rosrun uvc_camera uvc_camera_node 
[ INFO] [1416870421.617654535]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1416870421.617885710]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/przemek/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml
opening /dev/video0
pixfmt 0 = 'YUYV' desc = 'YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)'
  discrete: 640x480:   1/30 1/15 
  discrete: 352x288:   1/30 1/15 
  discrete: 320x240:   1/30 1/15 
  discrete: 176x144:   1/30 1/15 
  discrete: 160x120:   1/30 1/15 
  discrete: 1280x1024:   2/15 1/5 
  int (Brightness, 0, id = 980900): -10 to 10 (1)
  int (Contrast, 0, id = 980901): 0 to 20 (1)
  int (Saturation, 0, id = 980902): 0 to 10 (1)
  int (Gamma, 0, id = 980910): 100 to 200 (1)
  int (Gain, 0, id = 980913): 32 to 48 (1)
  menu (Power Line Frequency, 0, id = 980918): 0 to 2 (1)
    0: Disabled
    1: 50 Hz
    2: 60 Hz
  int (Sharpness, 0, id = 98091b): 0 to 10 (1)
select timeout in grab
select timeout in grab
```

and everything seems to be ok...

Rosnode and rostopic list:

```
przemek@przem:/opt/ros/indigo/share/uvc_camera$ rosnode list 
/rosout
/uvc_camera

przemek@przem:/opt/ros/indigo/share/uvc_camera$ rostopic list 
/camera_info
/image_raw
....
```

When I run ar_single_pose I get error:

```
process[camera/uvc_camera_node-4]: started with pid [22299]
process[ar_pose-5]: started with pid [22314]
[ INFO] [1416872056.747424013]: camera calibration URL: file:///opt/ros/indigo/share/uvc_camera/camera_calibration.yaml
[ INFO] [1416872057.006555638]: Starting ArSinglePublisher
[ INFO] [1416872057.008427734]:     Publish transforms: 1
[ INFO] [1416872057.013649211]:     Publish visual markers: 1
[ INFO] [1416872057.015248159]:     Threshold: 100
[ INFO] [1416872057.016890548]:     Marker Width: 152.4
[ INFO] [1416872057.019849023]:     Reverse Transform: 0
[ INFO] [1416872057.023319574]:     Marker frame: ar_marker
[ INFO] [1416872057.027037854]:     Use history: 1
[ INFO] [1416872057.046105711]:     Marker Center: (0.0,0.0)
[ INFO] [1416872057.046718919]: Subscribing to info topic
opening /dev/video0
pixfmt 0 = 'YUYV' desc = 'YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)'
  discrete: 640x480:   1/30 1/15 
  discrete: 352x288:   1/30 1/15 
  discrete: 320x240:   1/30 1/15 
  discrete: 176x144:   1/30 1/15 
  discrete: 160x120:   1/30 1/15 
  discrete: 1280x1024:   2/15 1/5 
  int (Brightness, 0, id = 980900): -10 to 10 (1)
  int (Contrast, 0, id = 980901): 0 to 20 (1)
  int (Saturation, 0, id = 980902): 0 to 10 (1)
  int (Gamma, 0, id = 980910): 100 to 200 (1)
  int (Gain, 0, id = 980913): 32 to 48 (1)
  menu (Power Line Frequency, 0, id = 980918): 0 to 2 (1)
    0: Disabled
    1: 50 Hz
    2: 60 Hz
  int (Sharpness, 0, id = 98091b): 0 to 10 (1)
select timeout in grab
[ INFO] [1416872059.116906053]: *** Camera Parameter ***
--------------------------------------
SIZE = 320, 240
Distortion factor = 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 
--------------------------------------
[ INFO] [1416872059.117126682]: Loading pattern
[ INFO] [1416872059.118051380]: Subscribing to image topic
[ERROR] [1416872060.024344493]: Rectified topic '/camera/image_rect' requested but camera publishing '/camera/camera_info' is uncalibrated
[ERROR] [1416872090.108035723]: Rectified topic '/camera/image_rect' requested but camera publishing '/camera/camera_info' is uncalibrated
[ERROR] [1416872120.186654733]: Rectified topic '/camera/image_rect' requested but camera publishing '/camera/camera_info' is uncalibrated
```

**[ERROR] [1416872150.188997696]: Rectified topic '/camera/image_rect' requested but camera publishing '/camera/camera_info' is uncalibrated**

and now: rosnode and rostopic list:

```
przemek@przem:/opt/ros/indigo/share/uvc_camera$ rosnode list 
/ar_pose
/camera/image_proc
/camera/uvc_camera_node

przemek@przem:/opt/ros/indigo/share/uvc_camera$ rostopic list 

/camera/camera_info
/camera/image_raw
...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198187/problem-with-ar_pose,-error:-rectified-topic-%27/camera/image_rect%27-requested-but-camera-publishing-%27/camera/camera_info%27-is-uncalibrated**/) by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2014-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you really calibrated your camera using the camera calibrator?

http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration

Some camera drivers may publish an empty uncalibrated camera_info along with the image, which seems to be the case as your calib matrix contains all zeros and the distortion factor is the default 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on 2014-11-25**:
EDIT / I found solution!

Yes, but I was doing it in wrong way. Because commit button didn't work, I manually copied file from calibration tar to appropriate localisation.

How to repair commit button in calibration: http://tinyurl.com/nksyrdm

I calibrated it again and commited setting to driver.